# htaccess rewrite removing consecutive numbers in filenames

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have old urls which contain consecutive numbers I like to redirect via htaccess, for example:

(im not allowed to post links yet)

www.example.com/just/another/path2/name-789-e-11-2.html
www.example.com/its/another/path3/name-789-e-11-5.html

On the new system the appended numbers dont exist anymore:

www.example.com/just/another/path2/name-789-e-11.html
www.example.com/its/another/path3/name-789-e-11.html

So the filename in the different paths is now the same, without the appended consecutive numbers.

Does anybody have a solution for that? I tried different but none of them worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as **first rule** in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+\d+)-\d+\.html$ /$1.html
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, it worked in both cases.